# How do I customize the default 404 response with Dingo API and Lumen framework

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, lumen, dingo-api

I am building a REST API using Lumen framework and the Dingo API library. Everything works well except that I don't know how I can customize the default 404 response done by Dingo when no route matches.

My `route.php` file looks like this :

```
$api->version('v4', ['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api.auth|api.throttle', 'limit' => 100, 'expires' => 5], function ($api) {
    $api->get('members', 'App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@members_GET');
    // More routes down there
});
```

And then when no route matches, I get a response like that :

```
{
  "message": "404 Not Found",
  "status_code": 404
}
```

I tried to edit `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` but it does not work.

I would like to customize the message part to have something more appropriate to the context of my API. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove API_DOMAIN from your .ENV-file

Or use API_PREFIX or API_DOMAIN, not both, they said... works with me.